# How do I upgrade MinTTY in Git for Windows

Tags: mintty, git-for-windows, software-update

I appreciate that this is borderline off-topic, but it does "directly involve programming or programming tools" so I figure it's just about OK...

I've just installed a newly downloaded version of Git for Windows, and noticed that in the Options dialog, the title bar says "mintty 2.8.5 is available". According to the About dialog, I currently have version 2.8.4.

I assume it's telling me that there's a new version because I am able to upgrade it myself, but I can't find any information about how to do so. I've downloaded the zip file from [mintty.github.io](http://mintty.github.io/), but don't really want to have to build it manually if I can avoid it.

Is there some way to do this, or is the easiest option just to wait for an updated build of Git For Windows that includes the new version of MinTTY?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[mintty](https://github.com/mintty/mintty) is a terminal emulator program available for Cygwin and msys2 environment. In both environment, [mintty](https://github.com/mintty/mintty) can be compiled as 32bit and 64bit. Hence it will be easy to deploy if users/package maintainer compile themselves with their own toolchain. Here are the two mainstream toolchain associated with mintty.

- Cygwin: You can search the full package name[cygwin package search](https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-grep.cgi). Cygwin maintains [multiple mirror URLs](https://cygwin.com/mirrors.html) to download a package. Here is one of the mirror:

  - 32bit: https://mirrors.kernel.org/sourceware/cygwin/x86/release/mintty/
  - 64bit: https://mirrors.kernel.org/sourceware/cygwin/x86_64/release/mintty/
- msys2: [msys2](http://www.msys2.org/) also maintains [mirror URLs](https://github.com/Alexpux/MSYS2-packages/tree/master/pacman-mirrors) to download. You can browse whole packages list in http://repo.msys2.org/. Open that URL in a browser. As mintty need msys2 dynamic library, it can be found in msys2 directory. Search mintty in these webpages:

  - 32bit: http://repo.msys2.org/msys/i686/
  - 64bit: http://repo.msys2.org/msys/x86_64/

To use it in Git-For-Windows, download the mintty tarball file from msys2 links according to your installed one 32bit or 64bit. You can find `mintty.exe` in that .tar.xz file's `usr/bin` folder. Extract and place that executable in Git-For-Windows installation folder e.g. `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin`.

Note: Mintty need a dynamic library (e.g. `cygwin1.dll` or `msys-2.0.dll`) and a shell (e.g. bash.exe, dash.exe etc.) or a command line program to run. And it should be placed in `/usr/bin` or `/bin` folder as per your specific environment. For Cygwin specifically, you also need `cygwin-console-helper.exe` to hide the console window (conhost.exe process). In msys2 environment, mintty version may be lower than the Cygwin one.

Comment: To update mintty package with msys2, put `mintty.exe` under directory `MSYS2_ROOT/usr/bin` to replace the old one.

Comment: Supplementary note: you can find `msys-2.0.dll` in msys2-runtime-<version>-<platform>.pkg.tar, in the repo links in the answer.

Comment: unable to find that msys-2.0.dll after extracting that http://repo.msys2.org/msys/x86_64/mintty-1~3.0.0-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz @Len

Comment: @SagarPatel The question is about mintty, so I didn't mention msys2. You can download it from here http://repo.msys2.org/msys/x86_64/msys2-runtime-3.0.6-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz.

Comment: @SagarPatel which is a completely different file to where I said you could find it

Comment: I did exactly that in my Git installation in C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin , I placed the mintty.exe and now there is an error saying "mintty.exe - Entry Point not Found" and it crashes

Answer (score 4):

I was having a similar issue with Git Bash saying "mintty 3.5.2 available". I simply used the following command in Git Bash.

```
git update-git-for-windows
```

It re-ran the installer and updated both my Git for Windows and mintty versions to the latest ones. The command is only valid from Git for Windows v2.16.1(2) though.